# change compiler in CMAKE sub_directory CMakeLists.txt file

Tags: cmake

I would like to change CMAKE_C_COMPILER and CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER in an inner sub_directory being compiled as part of a bigger project.

changing from GNU to intel compiler. however, outside of this directory nothing has to chagne.

is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using `add_subdirectory` consider making the subdirectory a self-contained CMake project, which can be configured and built independently of the bigger project. You can then add the subdirectory to your bigger project as an external project by using the [ExternalProject_Add](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) command.

Comment: I think this is probably the best bet

Answer (score 1):

It depends, how you organize your project.
If it is not single CMakeLists.txt for whole project, but one per each sub folder - just try to change CMAKE_C_COMPILER before project() definition. 
It should affect only this project definition.

Comment: This doesn't work. CMake doesn't let u simple change the CMAKE_C_FLAGS an CMAKE_CXX_FLAGX in one of the sub projects.

Comment: It looks like you right. I've tried it on latest 2.8.x and it is not possible any more - I've got infinit loop in configuration (was working before 2.6.x). Here the same issue described http://www.itk.org/Bug/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=8193&history=1

Comment: I did exactly this and CMake 3.6.2 entered an infinite loop.